# Having SSL enabled on admin, but disabled on post preview and live preview?

Tags: wp-admin, theme-customizer, ssl, previews

I was trying to enable SSL on the admin of my WordPress site by adding following code in the `wp-config.php`

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

This works, however not only the admin area, the live preview area in the Customize and post previewing page has been turned to https too, where it shows a broken page because the font-end isn't ssl.

I need to keep the front-end running over `http`, so my question is, login over `https` but preview over `http`, is it possible?

Comment: hmm, in no definition that I have heard of, a "post preview" is part of front end. Or in other words, you can not preview over http and be "secure" (https does not actually provide that much security, it is more relevant to privacy)

Comment: Why aren't you enabling https on the front-end too? I can't think of a good reason not to. Any performance impact is negligible, especially against the security benefits. Not to mention avoiding Chrome telling all your users that you're not secure, [come July](https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/8/16991254/chrome-not-secure-marked-http-encryption-ssl).